# SP2013 installation stuck at then end because of disconnected media

Tags: 2013, installation

I'm installing SP 2013 on a VM. The iso file is on my local computer. So I opened vsphere client, and attach the iso file. Start installation of sharepoint 2013 server.

My computer crashed, so vsphere got close, and the media on the vm got disconnected while the installation process was running...

So the sharepoint installation is stuck at "End of installation. This operation may take several minutes".

I insert the iso again, but still stuck ... any ideas about what can I do to go through this ?
I can't close the installation wizard though, and I don't think kill the process would be a great idea ...

By the way, i'm now installing it on a 2nd server, and the wizard is stuck at the same point for 5 minutes now ...

My iso file is good because I already installed a SP server with this one ...
I'll wait for my 2nd server to end the installation if possible. And see if any problem appear

**UPDATE** : Installation ended on the first server (the one where iso was disconnect during installation)... So everything seems ok, it just takes about 1 hour...

Answer (score 0):

Installation ended on the first server (the one where iso was disconnect during installation)...

So everything seems ok, it just takes about 1 hour...

I see posts on google where people had to wait about 8 hours...